# AES 256 encrypt and Decrypt in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes

Hello I have an issue when I trying to decrypt an Ogg file whit java that was encrypted whit PHP

this is the function that creates the encrypted file

[PHP crypt function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQneX.png)

I used this code with java but the generated file is corrupt

```
public static String decrypt(String input, String key){
        byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(input);
        if(bytes.length < 17) {
            return null;
        }
        String result = null;
        //byte[] ivBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 0, 16);
        //byte[] contentBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 16, bytes.length);


        try {
            //Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            

            Key skey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
            // Set the appropriate size for mInitVec by Generating a New One
            AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();
            byte[] mInitVec = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey, new IvParameterSpec(mInitVec));
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
            
            String uploadedFileLocation = "C:\\test3.ogg";
            
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            fs.write(decrypted);
            fs.close();
            
            result ="decrypted";
         
        } catch (
                Exception ex
        ) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried with: "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" ?

Comment: yes, I tried and I get "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TLDR: **it's mostly the IV**

For encryption modes like CBC that use an IV (initialization vector, or sometimes nonce) decryption must use the same IV (*and* key) as encryption did. In addition, a block mode like CBC generally requires padding and unpadding the data, and OpenSSL as used by PHP does so using the 'standard' PKCS5/7 padding which Java also supports but must select.

```
$ cat 71865785.php
<?php
  $data = "some test data";
  $cipher = "aes-256-cbc";
  $key = "reallyrealsekritreallyrealsekrit"; // for test only, real key should not be human-chosen
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher));
  echo base64_encode($iv)."\n".openssl_encrypt($data,$cipher,$key,0,$iv)."\n";
?>
$ php 71865785.php
LGQXy7XF8DHBilN4Kb8Xrg==
DWI/F97O5e/NGD2czp2OUA==
$ cat SO71865785.java
//nopackage
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.*;

public class SO71865785 /* decrypt from PHP */ {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] key = "reallyrealsekritreallyrealsekrit".getBytes("ASCII"); // for test only
    byte[] iv = Base64.getDecoder().decode("LGQXy7XF8DHBilN4Kb8Xrg==");
    byte[] ctext = Base64.getDecoder().decode("DWI/F97O5e/NGD2czp2OUA==");

    Cipher ciph = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    ciph.init (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    byte[] plain = ciph.doFinal(ctext);
    System.out.println ("len="+plain.length+":"+new String(plain,"ASCII"));
    // if non-ASCII chars are present must use encoding to match encrypting system which is not known
  }
}
$ javac SO71865785.java
$ java -cp . SO71865785
len=14:some test data
```

For a real application of course you wouldn't use hardcoded data (and usually shouldn't hardcode key either) and the method of passing the data produced by the PHP app to the Java app varies (a lot!). One not-uncommon way is to concatenate the IV and ciphertext (and preferably a MAC or auth tag as well) for transmission and/or storage and then separate them with code like the two `Arrays.copyOfRange` you have in comments, but for this demo I simply base64-ed each piece (openssl_encrypt already does base64 by default).

Note for AES-256 the key must be exactly 32 bytes (and should be arbitrary bytes, not characters recognizable to a human). In PHP/OpenSSL if you provide less than required it silently pads with zero bytes (aka NUL), but Java does not; if you have a too-short `byte[]` in Java you can conveniently zero-pad it with e.g. `Arrays.copyOf(poorkey,32)`.

Comment: I will try and I tell you the results, thanks for your answer